# '80-'90s movie where the main character gets into different films

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I watched this movie in early '90s. The main character gets into different films (but I'm not sure). There was definitely a scene where he drives a car with the Nazis and decides to play dice to decide who will jump. The Nazi rolls a '6' and the guy rolls a '7' (on a 6-digit die)!!! The Nazi jumps out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When you say _"the main character gets into different films"_, do you mean that he enters the world of different films, like the boy in _Last Action Hero_? Also, can you tell us anything more about the main character, or any other characters, or any other films the main characters was in?

Comment: Could be something like [Stay Tuned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stay_Tuned_(film))

Comment: I was thinking of the Purple Rose of Cairo but I'm sure if anyone thinks that's scifi...

Comment: There were Nazis in "Dead men don't wear plaid" but I can't remember a jump from a vehicle

Comment: Thank you all!!! It's definitely not "Dead men don't wear plaid"

Comment: & not Purple Rose of Cairo

Comment: stay tuned I'll reconsider, but in my opinion it's not that either. I remember that the main character is not a boy, but a mature uncle. And alas, except for the episode with the fascists... in my opinion, he still got into a zombie movie. And it's not The Video Dead

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be German 1985 comedy movie [*"Die Einsteiger"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0stQKkGg7DA) (loosely translated as The Get-In-ers? No idea of an official English name)

Storyline [from IMDB site](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089077/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0_tt_7_nm_1_q_Die%2520Einsteiger):

> Movie fan Mike has invented a machine with which he is able to take part in every movie which is currently running on his video tape recorder. But he and his friend Tommy are watched while trying out this new device and soon two electronic companies are on their trail to discover the secret of this invention.

[The scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlIaNCqT_OE) with main characters playing dice with Nazis in a truck is supposed to look as if taken from an Indiana Jones movie, playing from a videocassette, to which the main characters were transported in using the device.

Comment: HOORAY! Is it really this movie